# why arrays on the stack throw errors and on the heap not

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I understand that the size of arrays in C++ is fixed.
In the first example `numbers` is allocated on the stack, while in the second `numbers` is allocated on the heap.

First:

```cpp
int main() {
    int numbers[10];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        numbers[i] = i;

    return 0;
}
```

Second:

```cpp
int main() {
    int* numbers = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        numbers[i] = i;

    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is, why the first code snipped throws the error `stack smashing detected`, while the second code snipped does not.

Some people would explain that on the heap, when I insert elements outside of the array boundaries, I'm just writing to memory locations I don't own, which can lead to unpredicted behaviours. So then why doesn't the same happen on the stack?

Comment: Because stack smashing has historically been used to exploit programs and, as you discovered, compilers bake in defenses against such attacks. Better to have the program crash than have people take over your computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why

Comment: "can lead to unpredicted behaviours. So then why doesn't the same happen on the stack?" well, "unpredictable" exactly means that you cannot predict it, that it can be different when the moon is in a different phase, or when you change something on your code. The better question is "Why does it behave predicatbly in one case?" and @Botje explained that

Comment: dont fall into the trap of expecting a crash or runtime error when your code has undefined behavior. Apaering to work fine is the worst incarnation of UB

Comment: @asa - If you were to try a second heap allocation (or a `delete[] numbers`), you might very well get a "heap corruption detected" at that point.

Comment: So you predicted that the unpredictable behaviour would be the same in both cases and it wasn't, but you don't consider that unpredictable?

Comment: If you want errors about particular kind of UBs consistently then you have to specially instrument your program with run-time sanitisers/checkers of that kind of UBs. Those checkers will reduce performance so are typically only used for debugging.